# How to show heavy data quickly

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am developing a website using ASP.NET 4.0. I want to fetch & show 6,000 records to the user when show button is clicked I dont wanna use neither paging nor griview. A simple table will do what all i have to achieve is to show the records as quicker as possible. If i try to fill records clientside like

```
<html><table id='tbl'></table></html>
<script>
function getDataFromService()
{
    PageMethods.GetData(filltable)
}
function filltable(result){
  for(int i=0;i<=result.length-1;i++)
  {
     var td= $('<td\>').append(result[i]) ;
     var tr=$('<tr\>').append(td);
     $('#tbl').append(tr);
   }
}
```

This trick fails as it takes time to create 6,000 rows dynamically. I tried virtual scrolling i.e Fetch only 100 records & when user scrolls fetch next 1000 but i am not able to find the proper way to achieve this. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: that is called [Lazy Loading!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no *fast* way to retrieve and display 6000 records on a web page. It will take time just to render that many rows to the screen.

You have two options:

- Pagination
- Continuous scrolling

It sounds like the continuous scrolling pattern will work best for you. Here's an article that discusses how to implement the technique using jQuery:

http://www.go4coding.com/post/2011/04/11/Auto-loading-content-on-page-scroll-in-aspnet-using-jquery.aspx

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by others, adding 6000 rows will always be noticeably slow, but you can reduce the time **CONSIDERABLY** if you build a long string with all the html for the  tags before calling append(), and you don't need to use $() to build the rows, that's also very expensive.

The following code saves several thousand calls to `$.append()` and `$()` and will render the table quite faster:

```
function getDataFromService()
{
    PageMethods.GetData(filltable)
}

function filltable(result){
  var html = '';

  for(int i=0;i<=result.length-1;i++)
  {
     html += '<tr><td>' + result[i] + '</td></tr>'         
  }
   $('#tbl').append(html);
}
```